# Authentication failure in SOAP callout to Experian QAS Pro, possibly due to invalid element in SOAP message

Tags: apex, soap, callout, wsdl2apex

I am using the Experian QAS Pro for Address validation and am having a problem getting my calls to work. I used a SOAP plugin (Chrome Wizdler) and did successfully submit a call, but something in Apex land is making things slightly different when I do the callout from Salesforce, which is resulting in an authentication failure. I used FuseIT SFDC Explorer to import [the WSDL](https://ws3.ondemand.qas.com/ProOnDemand/V3/ProOnDemandService.asmx?WSDL%20%22the%20WSDL:), along with some manual tweaks I have documented below. Here is the message that does work, generated by Wizdler:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Header>
        <QAQueryHeader xmlns="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03">
            <QAAuthentication>
                <Username>myusername</Username>
                <Password>mypassword</Password>
            </QAAuthentication>
            <Security>
            </Security>
        </QAQueryHeader>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <QACanSearch xmlns="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03">
            <Country>AUS</Country>
            <Engine/>
            <Layout>qaDefault</Layout>
        </QACanSearch>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And here's the message generated by the Salesforce Apex code that gets an authentication failure. You can see that instead of having the element name "QAQueryHeader", it has "query_header". I guess that's the problem. Just not sure about the fix.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header>
        <query_header xmlns="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03">
            <QAAuthentication>
                <Username>myusername</Username>
                <Password>mypassword</Password>
            </QAAuthentication>
            <Security/>
        </query_header>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <QACanSearch xmlns="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03">
            <Country>AUS</Country>
            <Engine/>
            <Layout>QaDefault</Layout>
        </QACanSearch>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I made two changes to the code generated from the WSDL. Firstly, I deleted 10 duplicate instances of the following 4 lines inside the subclass wwwQasComOndemand201103.PortType:

```
private String information_header_hns = 'information_header=http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03';
public wwwQasComOndemand201103.QAQueryHeader query_header;
private String query_header_hns = 'query_header=http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03';
public wwwQasComOndemand201103.QAInformation information_header;
```

Secondly, I changed this declaration inside the wwwQasComOndemand201103.EngineType subclass to be of type String. Given the successful and failing versions of the SOAP message both generate the same empty XML Engine element, I don't think that this is causing a problem.

```
public wwwQasComOndemand201103.EngineEnumType input;
```

Comment: Is this the [WSDL](https://ws.ondemand.qas.com/ProOnDemand/V3/ProOnDemandService.asmx?WSDL)? Without some detail of your "manual tweaks" I'm not sure that even someone who knows FuseIT SFDC Explorer well will be able to help you.

Comment: @KeithC, thanks for your question. I've only shown the messages generated according to the WSDL I used. The actual WSDL is linked to on [this page](https://ws3.ondemand.qas.com/ProOnDemand/V3/ProOnDemandService.asmx). I'll look into listing the tweaks tomorrow; think there was only one of consequence, which was to change the type of a variable from an enum to a string to overcome an error.

Comment: Have listed all code changes in the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the QAQueryHeader you will need to manually adjust the `query_header_hns` string that is generated.

In `public class QAPortType` change:

```
private String query_header_hns = 'query_header=http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03';
```

to:

```
private String query_header_hns = 'QAQueryHeader=http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03';
```

Then, when called with this anonymous apex:

```
wwwQasComOndemand201103.QAPortType service = new wwwQasComOndemand201103.QAPortType();

service.query_header = new wwwQasComOndemand201103.QAQueryHeader();
service.query_header.QAAuthentication = new wwwQasComOndemand201103.QAAuthentication();
service.query_header.QAAuthentication.Username = 'myusername';
service.query_header.QAAuthentication.Password = 'mypassword';

string country = 'AUS';
wwwQasComOndemand201103.EngineType engine = null;
string layout = 'QaDefault';
wwwQasComOndemand201103.QASearchOk_element result = service.DoCanSearch(country,engine,layout);
```

It produces this CALLOUT_REQUEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <env:Header>
    <QAQueryHeader xmlns="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03">
      <QAAuthentication>
        <Username>myusername</Username>
        <Password>mypassword</Password>
      </QAAuthentication>
      <Security />
    </QAQueryHeader>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <QACanSearch xmlns="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03">
      <Country>AUS</Country>
      <Engine />
      <Layout>QaDefault</Layout>
    </QACanSearch>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I'll have a look through the source for the FuseIT SFDC Explorer to see if I can tidy up some of the generated code for this WSDL.